# Is there a simple way to convert the **params dict into actual variables?

Tags: python, variables, parameters

Is there a simple way to convert the **params dict into actual variables that won't generate a compilation error.

```py
def function(**params):
    for key in ['name', 'partial', 'startswith', 'endswith', 'useVisibleParam', 'invalid_shapes']:
        if key in params.keys():
            vars()[key] = params[key]
        else:
            vars()[key] = None

    if startswith is not None:
        pass


function(name = 'name',
         partial = 'partial',
         startswith = 'startswith',
         endswith = 'endswith',
         useVisibleParam = 'useVisibleParam',
         invalid_shapes = 'invalid_shapes')
```

Generates: NameError: name 'startswith' is not defined

Comment: what do you mean by "*compilation error*"? `print(params.get('name'), params.get('partial'))` all the other code is unnecessary. Or explicitly define the parameters if they are needed `def function(name=None, partial=None, **params)`

Comment: the closest thing would be:
`name = params.get('name', None)`

Comment: @Hafnernuss please don't suggest that, it's the wrong approach

Comment: Are you looking to create "variable variables" a la https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: I modified my question to show the error I'm talking about.

Comment: @Hafnernuss I was trying to make it smaller and I was hoping I could loop it.

Comment: @mozway what do you mean? At the time of writing it was simply a shorter way of writing what OP already had...

Comment: @Hafnernuss I'm talking about your link on how to create variable names, it's a bad thing to suggest to potential beginners

Comment: @mozway removed - but may I ask why? simply because it's "dangerous" when tampering with those "internals" directly?

Comment: It leads to error-prone and unmaintainable code.

Comment: @Hafnernuss I think what you suggested about `name = params.get('name', None)` is the best way to condense the code for creating the actual variables.

Comment: @Hafnernuss dangerous, non-pythonic, useless, error-prone, bug-prone, inefficient, ambiguous…